# How to deselect Jlist item on some event in java

Tags: java, swing, selection, jlist

could any one suggest me any method or any other way in java that i could deselect my jlist item when some event occurs?
    i tried this but this does not seem to work

```
myJList.setSelectedIndex(-1);
myJList.ensureIndexIsVisible(-1);
```

Comment: trying random api rarely is a good solution strategy (why would you thing that ensureIndexIsVisible has anything to do with selection?) - instead read the api doc and/or a good basic tutorial, f.i. the online swing tutorial linked to in the swing tag description

Answer (score 42, accepted):

Try [myJList.clearSelection();](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/JList.html#clearSelection%28%29) It clears the **selection(s)** on your [JList](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/list.html) object.
If multiple list items selected together, they can also be deselected via this method.

Comment: Hello Deporter please read my This Question about loading a .Tif Image and please suggest me how to do it? i had put my code also which i tried [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9634472/how-to-set-tif-image-to-imageiconin-java]

Comment: @AshishDonvir ok i will take a look at it now.